tkinter.TclError: invalid command name
I have the following problem in my code block.
After pressing the "cek_ue" button
I want the value "uye_ekle_f" to be destroyed
uye_ekle_f.destroy()

but it gives an error, I don't understand why, can you explain this and it gives the same error in other comboboxes in the same way
mistake:
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!ctkframe.!labelframe4.!ctkcombobox.!ctkcanvas"

def uye_ekle():
    baslik("Gruba Üye Ekle")
    kapat()
    
    uye_ue = tk.LabelFrame(ekran,text="Çekilecek Üye Listesi Seç",font=copy_font,bg="#313131",fg="white")
    
    kanal_ue = tk.LabelFrame(ekran,text="Üye Eklenecek Kanal Seç",font=copy_font,bg="#313131",fg="white")
    
    zaman_ue = tk.LabelFrame(ekran,text="Zaman Aralığı Seç",font=copy_font,bg="#313131",fg="white")

    veri = []
    with open(path + "\\users\\users.json") as dosya:
        n = json.load(dosya)
        for i in n:
            veri.append(i.get("no"))

    uye_ekle_f = tk.LabelFrame(ekran,text="Hesap Seç",font=copy_font,bg="#313131",fg="white")
    uye_ekle_f.place(relheight=0.11,relwidth=0.97,x=10)
    num = StringVar(value="Hesap Seç")
    hesab = CTkComboBox(uye_ekle_f,values=veri,variable=num)
    hesab.place(relx=.5,rely=.5,anchor="center")
    
    def basla():
            Thread(target=oto, args=(cekim(),)).start()

    cek_ue = CTkButton(ekran,text="Kanalları Çek",width=200,height=50,fg_color=(mor2,mor),hover_color=mor2,command=basla)
    cek_ue.place(relx=.5, rely=.2, anchor="center")
    
    async def cekim():
        try:
            uye_ekle_f.destroy()
            devre_disi()
            cek_ue.configure(text="Lütfen Bekleyin...",state="disabled")
            app = Client(path + "\\users\\" + num.get())
            await app.start()
            k_id = await app.get_me()
            k_id = k_id.id
            channel = []
            file = []
            liste = path + "\\veri\\"
            n = glob.glob(liste + "*.json")
            dosyalar = [os.path.basename(dosya) for dosya in n]
            for x in dosyalar:
                file.append(x)
                try:

                    with open(path + "\\veri\\" + x,"r",encoding="utf-8") as f:
                        data = json.load(f)

                except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:pass

                id = 0
                for i in data:
                    if 'id' in i:
                        id += 1

                channel.append(x + "   -   Üye : " + str(id))
            
            channel2 = []
            kanal_id = []
            async for x in app.get_dialogs():
                if x.chat.type == enums.ChatType.SUPERGROUP:
                    chat = x.chat
                    uye = 0
                    uye2 = chat.members_count
                    async for l in app.get_chat_members(chat.id):
                            uye+=1
                            if str(l.user.id) == k_id:
                                print("Varız")
                            else:
                                pass

                    if uye == uye2 or uye2 < uye:
                        uye_var = True
                        channel2.append(chat.title + " - Üye Sayısı: " + str(uye))
                        kanal_id.append(int(chat.id))
                    else:
                        uye_var = False

        except AttributeError:
              messagebox.showerror(title="Aevgram",message="Geçerli Hesap Girin")
              return uye_ekle()

        cek_ue.place_forget()
        menu()
        
        def yazi(value):
            yaz.set(f"{int(zaman.get())}")
        
        uye_ue.place(x=10,relwidth=0.97,relheight=0.11)
        secim = StringVar(value="Üye Listesi Seç")
        UyeSec = CTkComboBox(uye_ue,values=channel,variable=secim)
        UyeSec.place(relx=.5,rely=.5,anchor="center")
        
        kanal_ue.place(x=10,y=70,relwidth=0.97,relheight=0.11)
        sec2 = StringVar(value="Kanal Seç")
        kanalSec = CTkComboBox(kanal_ue,values=channel2,variable=sec2)
        kanalSec.place(relx=.5,rely=.5,anchor="center")
        
        zaman_ue.place(x=10,y=140,relwidth=0.97,relheight=0.11)
        yaz = StringVar(value = "30")
        zmn = CTkLabel(zaman_ue,textvariable=yaz,font=font)
        zmn.pack()
        zaman = CTkSlider(zaman_ue, from_=2, to=60,command=yazi)
        zaman.pack()
        
        await app.stop()
        
        async def cekis():

            zaman_ue.destroy()
            uye_ekle_f.destroy()
            
        
        def basla2():
             Thread(target=oto, args=(cekis(),)).start()
             
        cek_ue2 = CTkButton(ekran,text="Ekleme İşlemi",width=200,height=50,fg_color=(mor2,mor),hover_color=mor2,command=basla2)
        cek_ue2.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="center")


maybe you destroyed it before and now it doesn't exists.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

is your code correctly formatted? Do you have functions inside functions? If not then edit question and format code correctly.

I haven't destroyed it before

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

maybe you destroyed one of other elements in ".!ctkframe.!labelframe4.!ctkcombobox.!ctkcanvas", or maybe you assigned it to other variable and you destroyed it with other variable. We can't run it to see what can make problem so you may have to debug it on your own - you may use print() for this.
